# Bootstrap datepicker with smalldate causing wrong day

Tags: c#, .net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

So I'm using the [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in my current .NET Application.
From an older state, my T-SQL DB still has a field with the type "smalldatetime", which cannot be easily changed.

This yields an output like this:

`01.03.2017 00:00:00`

This is causing the datepicker to highlight the wrong day (I guess fallback, since it is highlighting the current day). However, I figured out than if I remove the time-part of that date-string, it works.

I was thinking of a `trim`-like version to cut the date out of that smalldatetime-object, but I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET. I'm using the MVC-pattern and I have a model as well as a view. Please see following code:

**Model**

```
namespace AdminTool.Areas.Personal.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public partial class V_ADM_KuendigungEdit
    {
    [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? RL_Datum { get; set; }
    }

    // I was thinking of using an own getter-function, 
    // which yielded errors due to accessability
}
```

**View**

```
@model AdminTool.Areas.Personal.Models.V_ADM_KuendigungEdit

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RL_Datum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RL_Datum, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RL_Datum, "Kein gültiges Datum")
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to write an own getter-function called `public DateTime getRL_Datum() { }` but couldn't access it in my view. I tried `model=>getRL_Datum` as well as `model.getRL_Datum` - nothing worked here.

Any ideas on how to do it?